# Updating info into mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-update

I am trying to update my database by getting the id selected by user.

```
<form action="edit1.php" method="post">
<?php
                $query = "SELECT * FROM disease1;";
                $result = mysqli_query($dp, $query);
                echo "<table border=5>
                <tr>
                <th>Disease ID</th>
                <th>Disease</th>
                <th>Sub Disease</th>
                <th>Associated Disease</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                </tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row{'id'}."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row{'Disease'}."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row{'SubDisease'}."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row{'Associated_Disease'}."</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='radio' name='id' value='".$row[id]."'></td>";
    echo "</tr>";}              
    echo "</table>";                         
      ?>     <div> 
    <input type = 'submit' value = 'Update' name = 'submitupdate'>
```

My Edting page edit1.php

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','tool')  
    if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
    } 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM disease where id=".$_POST["id"];
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $count= mysqli_num_rows($result);
    echo $count;
    ?>
    <form action="update.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" name="id"/>
    Diease<input type="text" name="Disease" value="<?php echo $row['Disease'];?    >"/>
    SubDisease<input type="text" name="SubDisease" value="<?php echo $row['SubDisease'];?>"/>
    Associated Disease<input type="text" name="Associated_Disease" value="<?php echo $row['Associated_Disease'];?>"/>
    <input type="submit" value="update">
    </form>
```

My update.php

```
  <?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','tool');
     if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
    } 
    $disease=$_POST['Disease'];
    $SubDisease=$_POST['SubDisease'];
    $Associated_Disease= $_POST['Associated_Disease'];
    $id = $_POST ['id'];
    $update="Update disease1 set Disease='".$disease."', SubDisease='".$SubDisease."', Associated_Disease='".$Associated_Disease."' where     id=".$_POST["id"];
    mysqli_query($conn,$update);
?>
```

But the id is not reading and the value of the id is not passed to the update command. Can any one help me with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `fetch data` from your query result

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Then assign to form.

Complete code would be

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM disease where id=".$_POST["id"];
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$count= mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

<form action="update.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" name="id"/>
    Diease<input type="text" name="Disease" value="<?php echo $row['Disease'];?    >"/>
    SubDisease<input type="text" name="SubDisease" value="<?php echo $row['SubDisease'];?>"/>
    Associated Disease<input type="text" name="Associated_Disease" value="<?php echo $row['Associated_Disease'];?>"/>
    <input type="submit" value="update">
    </form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much . I've got the required output

Comment: @Saty.I have two submit buttons for both deleting and updtaing in  same form. Again I am facing the same problem.  Id is not reading and the value of the id is not passed to the editing as well as to the update page

Comment: Post a new question with two submit buttons!! and your new requirement!